# Fullcalendar v4 wrong color on background event with inverse-background rendering

Tags: fullcalendar

Why can't I get white color with two background events with inverse-background rendering?

I have found two similar questions but can't comment them (because of low reputation):
[FullCalendar 4 inverse-background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55725336/fullcalendar-4-inverse-background)

[How to avoid cumulative layer color in Fullcalendar inverse-background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50114102/how-to-avoid-cumulative-layer-color-in-fullcalendar-inverse-background)

Sample of problem in fullcalendar v4:
http://jsfiddle.net/hrvoje2/ye2gkb4a

Sample of good results in fullcalendar v3:
http://jsfiddle.net/gwpoofqk/1/

```
events: [
  {
    id: 2,
    start: '2018-05-02 10:00:00',
    end: '2018-05-02 11:00:00',
    color: 'blue',
    rendering: 'inverse-background'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    start: '2018-05-02 14:00:00',
    end: '2018-05-02 15:00:00',
    color: 'green',
    rendering: 'inverse-background'
  }
]
```

V3 renders ok (white), but v4 is blending colors (white and blue/green).
Documentation says 'Events that share the same id will be grouped together when this rendering happens'.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/background-events

Comment: if you believe the calendar is not behaving in the documented way then you should consider raising a bug about it - see https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs. We cannot fix internal fullCalendar bugs on StackOverflow - we can answer questions about your implementation of fullCalendar, and how you should interact with its API, but we cannot fix issues within the product itself.

Answer (score 1):

In v4, you have to use groupId to associate them together instead of id.
The docs are wrong right now (they say id).

Found that information in this bug report:
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4659

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/hrvoje2/pzu1qmvc/

```
events: [
  {
    id: 1,
    groupId: 1,
    start: '2018-05-02 10:00:00',
    end: '2018-05-02 11:00:00',
    color: 'blue',
    rendering: 'inverse-background'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    groupId: 1,
    start: '2018-05-02 14:00:00',
    end: '2018-05-02 15:00:00',
    color: 'green',
    rendering: 'inverse-background'
  }
]
```